# How to prove Rouche's theorem in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Actually I want to prove the open mapping theorem for $\mathbb R^2$ under C-R equation.

[The proof of complex version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) is same  as of $\mathbb R^2$ version before I encounter "Rouche's theorm" . So, to show that open mapping theorem holds in $\mathbb R^2$ under C-R, it suffices to show that "Rouche's" holds in it. But it seems hard for me in  multivariable-real analysis class .

So, I need

1. State of the Rouches's theorem in $\mathbb R^2$ under C-R equation;
2. Its proof

Comment: I have a different idea how to prove open mapping theorem. If your mapping satisfy C-R equation then each of its component is harmonic function. Harmonic functions are open. So you know that each component of your mapping is open. But I do not know if such mapping is in fact open.

Comment: @tom Okay. $f_1, f_2$ are harmonic. So, it suffices to show that harmonic implies open mapping. How can I do?

Comment: Use maximum principle, which implies that harmonic function cannot have local maximum or minimum. This shows that $f_i : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is open. But I do not know if this implies that $(f_1,f_2):\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is open.

Comment: @tom Since $R^2$ is a metric space, if we take half $\epsilon$-disk around $f_1 (x,y)$ and $ f_2 (x,y)$, $|f(x,y)-f(z,w)|\leq |f_1 (x,y)-f_1(z,w)|+|f_2(x,y)-f_2(z,w)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @tom Now the problem is to show that "maximum principle"

Comment: What you showed is that mapping is continuous if its components are continuous. But you want openness.

Comment: @tom I found this at Wiki "A composite of open maps is open and a composite of closed maps is closed. Also, a product of open maps is open. In contrast, a product of closed maps is not necessarily closed,.."

Comment: A product of open maps need not be open. For example  $x$ is open on $\mathbb R$ but $x^2$ is not.

Comment: @zhw Yeah... $x^2$ is not open. But $f=(x,x)$ is an open map.

Comment: From what space to what space  is (x,x) open?

Comment: from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$. Isn't it?

Comment: The line (x,x) is not open in the plane

Comment: Ah you're right. I confused two different notion.

Comment: The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#cite_note-baues55-13 talks about **categorical** product, I do not know what exactly that is but I'm sure that it is not normal product on $\mathbb{R}$ as you assumed.

Comment: Yeah, it's all my fault. :(